# In eclipse how to tell which 'wizard' invoked the actual wizard class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have the following configuration in my plugin.xml

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <category
        name="Oozie"
        id="com.myapp.wizards">
  </category>
  <wizard
        name="New file1"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        category="com.myapp.wizards"
        class="com.myapp.wizards.NewWizard"
        id="com.myapp.wizards.wizard1">
  </wizard>
  <wizard
        category="com.myapp.wizards"
        class="com.myapp.wizards.NewWizard"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        id="com.myapp.wizards.wizard2"
        name="New file 2">
  </wizard>
```

As you can see, both the wizards are pointing to the same class com.myapp.wizards.NewWizard. When the class is invoked I want to know which of the above wizard invoked it so that I can take different action based on the caller. i.e. if wizard1 calls name the file 'file1' and if wizard2 calls it name the file 'file2'.

What would be the best way to achieve this. I cannot see a 'id' field or get method on either the 'Wizard' class or the INewWizard interface that my NewWizard class implements.

I am currently developing on Eclipse SDK 4.2.2

Thanks for the help

Comment: I am not sure if it's a good practice that the class construction depends on the caller. For what I know, there is no way to differentiate between the two.

Comment: You could create two separate wizard classes that read the different files.  Each would call a common wizard class that does the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be direct way (indirectly you can create two derived classes and use it different wizards)